# Stoping the recv from server when client finishes reading and sending the file

Tags: c, sockets

Basically i use a recv in a while in order to read the data sent from my client. Client finishes reading the file and sending it but server remains in the while. How can i notify the server that the file sending is done meaning feof on clients side?

SERVER

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>      /*For Sockets*/
#include <sys/socket.h>     /*For Sockets*/
#include <netdb.h>      /*For gethostbyaddr()*/
#include <netinet/in.h>     /*For internet sockets*/
#include <dirent.h>


/*Function for creating the lof file of Server*/

void log_event (char *message,char *filename)
{

FILE *file; 
char *log_this;

time_t system_time; //Get the system time
time(&system_time);

log_this=strcat(ctime(&system_time),message); //Create the message to log 

/*Check for filename and log as appropiate*/

if (filename!=NULL)
    {
        file = fopen(filename,"a+"); 
        fprintf(file,"%s",log_this); /*writes the message*/
        fclose(file); /*done!*/     
    }
else    
    {
        file = fopen("ftp_tracelog.txt","a+"); 
        fprintf(file,"%s",log_this); /*writes the message*/
        fclose(file); /*done!*/ 
    }

}

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{

/*DECLERATIONS*/

char *filename; 
char message [1024];
char *temp;
char temp_2[1024];
char buf[1024];
char *p=buf;
ssize_t  bytesRemaining = 1024;
ssize_t  bytesRemaining2 = 50;
char request[50];
char command[5];
char c[50];
char copy[1024]="COPY_OF_";
FILE *fp;
DIR *dp;
char list[1024];
int port,sock,newsock,serverlen,clientlen,fname_len,recvMsgSize,i,len,count;


struct sockaddr_in server,client;
struct sockaddr *serverptr, *clientptr;
struct hostent *rem;
struct dirent *ep;     

/*END OF DECLERATIONS*/

/*Check for required arguments and get them as appropiate*/

if (argc < 2) { 
        /* Check if server's port number is given */
        printf("Please give the port number!!!\n");
        exit(1);
        }

/*if server's port number is given and filename for log is given*/

if(argc>2){
    filename=argv[1];
    port=atoi(argv[2]);
       }

/*If only port is given*/
if (argc==2){
    port=atoi(argv[1]);
    filename=NULL;
         }

temp="--Server is Starting!!--";
sprintf(message,"%s\n",temp);
log_event(message,filename);

/* Create socket */

if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{perror("socket"); exit(1); }

server.sin_family = PF_INET; /* Internet domain */
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* My Internet address */
server.sin_port = htons(port); /* The given port */
serverptr = (struct sockaddr *) &server;
serverlen = sizeof (server);

/* Bind socket to address */

if (bind(sock, serverptr, serverlen) < 0) {
perror("bind"); exit(1); }

/* Listen for connections */

if (listen(sock, 40) < 0) { /* 5 max. requests in queue */
perror("listen"); exit(1); }

temp="---Listening for connections to port";
sprintf(temp_2,"%d----",port);
sprintf(message,"%s:%s\n",temp,temp_2);
log_event(message,filename);

/*Accepting Connecttion*/

while(1) {
    clientptr = (struct sockaddr *) &client;
    clientlen = sizeof(client);

        /* Accept connection */
        if ((newsock = accept(sock, clientptr, &clientlen)) < 0){ 
        perror("accept"); exit(1);}

        /* Find client's address */
        if ((rem = gethostbyaddr((char *) &client.sin_addr.s_addr,
        sizeof (client.sin_addr.s_addr), client.sin_family)) == NULL) {
        perror("gethostbyaddr"); exit(1);}


temp="----Accepted connection from ";
sprintf(temp_2,"%s----", rem -> h_name);
sprintf(message,"%s:%s\n",temp,temp_2);
log_event(message,filename);

/* Create child for serving the client */
switch (fork()) {

case -1:
perror("fork"); exit(1);

case 0: /* Child process */



do{

    /* Receive message from client */
    if ((recvMsgSize = recv(newsock,request,sizeof(request),0))< 0)
    perror("recv() failed");



printf("%s\n",request);
//printf("%s\n",command);

/*IF YOU ARE GOING TO EXECUTE AN LS COMMAND*/

if (strcmp(request,"ls")==0)
    {
        dp = opendir ("./");

        if (dp != NULL)
          { /*LOG LS REQUEST*/

            temp="--Client ";
            sprintf(temp_2,"%s requested ls -------",rem -> h_name);
            sprintf(message,"%s:%s\n",temp,temp_2);
            log_event(message,filename);

            /*SEND ALL DIRECTORY LISTING*/    

            while (ep = readdir (dp))
            {
                strcpy(list,ep->d_name);
                //printf("sending:%s\n",list);
                if (send(newsock,list,sizeof(list), 0)!= sizeof(list))
                perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
            }
            //IF DIRECORY IS FINISHED SEND A LAST MESSAGE FOR ENDING

                (void) closedir (dp);
            if (send(newsock,"end",sizeof("end"), 0)!= sizeof("end"))
            perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");    
        }       

        else
        perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

    }

/*IF THE COMMAND IS PUT*/

if (strcmp(request,"put")==0) 
    {
    sprintf(buf,"");
    printf("execute put!!\n");
        do{
            ssize_t recvd;
            while (bytesRemaining) {

                if (( recvd =recv(newsock,p,bytesRemaining,0))< 0){
                perror("recv() failed");}
                bytesRemaining -= recvd;     // keep track of bytes left
                p += recvd;             
                    }
          }while (buf=="");
    strcat(copy,buf);

    fp=fopen(copy,"w+");
    count=0;

    while (c!="")
    {
        bzero(c,sizeof(c));
        if ((recvMsgSize = recv(newsock,c,sizeof(c),0))< 0)
        perror("recv() failed");
        fprintf(fp,"%s",c);

    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("!!DONE!!!!\n");
    //printf("%s",request);

    }

}while (strcmp(request,"end")!=0); //run until client sents end request

/*LOG EXIT OF CLIENT*/

temp="--Client";
    sprintf(temp_2,"%s is disconnected---",rem -> h_name);
    sprintf(message,"%s:%s\n",temp,temp_2);
    log_event(message,filename);

close(newsock); /* Close socket */
exit(0);
} /* end of switch */
}/*end of while*/
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{

int port, sock, serverlen,recvMsgSize,was_read;
int fname_len,msg_len,request_len;
char buf[256];
char *fname;
char request[50];
char list[1024];
char msg[512];
char op[1000];
char temp[5];
char *temp3;
char read;
FILE *fp;
char b[50];

struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr *serverptr;
struct hostent *rem;

temp3="put";

/* Are server's host name and port number given? */
if (argc < 3) {
printf("Please give host name and port number\n"); exit(1);

}

/* Create socket */
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
perror("socket");
exit(1);
}

/* Find server address */
if ((rem = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
herror("gethostbyname"); exit(1);
}

/* Convert port number to integer */
port = atoi(argv[2]);

/* Internet domain */
server.sin_family = PF_INET; 
bcopy((char *) rem -> h_addr, (char *) &server.sin_addr,
rem -> h_length);

/*Server's Internet address and port*/
server.sin_port = htons(port); 
serverptr = (struct sockaddr *) &server;
serverlen = sizeof(server);


if (connect(sock, serverptr, serverlen) < 0) { /* Request connection */
perror("connect"); 
exit(1); }

printf("Requested connection to host %s port %d\n", argv[1], port);



do{

printf("Please enter request\n:");
scanf("%s",request);

/* Send the string to the server */
if (send(sock,request,sizeof(request), 0)!= sizeof(request))
perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

if(strcmp(request,"ls")==0)
{
    sprintf(list,"");

    /*Recieve from server*/
    while(strcmp(list,"end")!=0){

        if ((recvMsgSize = recv(sock,list,sizeof(list),0))< 0)
        perror("recv() failed");

        if(strcmp(list,"end")!=0){
        printf("%s\n",list);
                    }
                    }
bzero(request,sizeof(request));
}

/*Command for put*/
if(strcmp(request,"put")==0)
{   bzero(request,sizeof(request));
    bzero(list,sizeof(list));
    printf("Please enter filename:\n");
    scanf("%s",list);
    //printf("%s",list);

    if (send(sock,list,sizeof(list), 0)!= sizeof(list))
    perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

    fp=fopen(list,"r");

    if(fp==NULL)

    {
    puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
        fclose (fp) ;
        exit(0);
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
    bzero(b,sizeof(b));
    int was_read = fread(b, sizeof(char),50,fp);

    if (send(sock,b,(sizeof (char) * was_read), 0)!= (sizeof (char) * was_read))
    perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }   

    zero(b,sizeof(b));
    if (send(sock,b,sizeof(b), 0)!= sizeof(b))
    perror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

}

}while (strcmp(request,"end")!=0);

close(sock); /* Close socket */
exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to have the client close the socket at the end of the file. The server will successfully receive 0 bytes from `recv()`, which means the other end cleanly closed the socket. I notice that you do not currently detect this return value in your server code, but you should.

I notice that your protocol has the ability to request more than one file. In this case, you will need to do something like send the number of bytes in the file before sending the actual file, then the server will know how many bytes to expect. Or, you can do like FTP does and open a second socket connection for the file data (one file at a time).

As a stylistic note, the indenting in your code is terrible. It's hard to read to find out where the blocks start and end. I would reject this code in a code review purely on reasons of formatting.

Comment: I agree. The best solution is a proper protocol; like a length being sent before the file contents.

Comment: No, please, don't suggest any more protocols with separate connections! (I've had my share of problems with NAT'ed and/or intercepted FTP, including an "interesting" case where a certain firewall NATted the addresses on the IP header, and a firewall "agent" installed on the end hosts NATted the PORT/227 FTP command/responses. You don't want to be in the middle of that).